# How to detect that an included modules methods will be overridden?

Tags: ruby

I have a module and I want to detect and raise if the class in to which it is included has/will have an instance method of the same name.

```
module Hello
  def self.included(base)
    puts base.instance_methods.include?(:foo)
  end
end
```

If the method is already defined the the module knows:

```
class Foo
  def foo; end
  include Hello # => true
end
```

But if the method is defined after inclusion, as is usual, then it does not know that its method is overridden:

```
class Foo
  include Hello # => false
  def foo; end
end
```

Comment: If you can find a way to predict the future I hope you use it to solve problems bigger than this one. There's no way of knowing what *will* happen in your program until it's actually executed.

Comment: I don't want to *predict* what will happen, but *react* to it if/when it does.

Comment: I don't think you're able to trap when your methods are overridden. It just happens. It's generally presumed to be the responsibility of the code composing the object to know what its doing, and if there's any situations where it'd need to send notifications, then that's something you'll have to handle yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: this sounds like a *very bad idea*. Inheritance is an important feature, why would you want to disallow it?

You need to detect when a method is added. You can use the `method_added` method for that. Something like this:

```
module Hello
  def self.included(base)
    puts base.instance_methods.include?(:foo)
    base.singleton_class.prepend(MethodBlocker)
  end

  module MethodBlocker
    def method_added(meth)
      puts 'foo method overridden' if meth == :foo
      super # see, inheritance is a Good Thing!
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include Hello # => false
  def foo; end
end
# false
# foo method overridden
```

Comment: This looks like the direction I need to take. I don't want to stop inheritance, just detect a method clash, normally I wouldn't need this and the reason is a long story :) Lets just say legacy code is involved.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to know what's below the `include Hello` line at the moment of reading/interpreting this line.

Meaning, while executing the file with the `Foo` class you can't say whether it has some method until you reach the last closing `end` of the class.

Thus, the easiest solution would be to simply include your module at the bottom of the class definition.

Comment: The downside to including at the bottom is that it will not catch monkey patching.